# Rg.Plugin.Popup weird behavior

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin.forms

I have made side menu using Rg.Plugins.Popups for Xamarin.

Everything is ok, but appearing animation doesn't work for some reason. As you can see menu just appears out of nowhere when it should look like disappearing animation.

[image]

```cs
FilterMenuCommand = new Command(() =>
{
    var contentView = new ReportsPageFilterMenuContentView(this);
    PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new ReportsPageFilterMenuPopupPage(contentView, this));
});
```

My PopupPage class:

```cs
public partial class ReportsPageFilterMenuPopupPage : PopupPage
{
    public ReportsPageFilterMenuPopupPage(ReportsPageFilterMenuContentView contentView, ReportsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializePageComponent(contentView, viewModel);
    }

    protected void InitializePageComponent(ReportsPageFilterMenuContentView contentView, ReportsViewModel viewModel, float width = 340.0f)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
            

        var moveAnimation = new MoveAnimation
        {
            DurationIn = 800,
            DurationOut = 600,
            EasingIn = Easing.SinIn,
            EasingOut = Easing.SinOut,
            HasBackgroundAnimation = true,
            PositionIn = MoveAnimationOptions.Right,
            PositionOut = MoveAnimationOptions.Right,
        };

        Animation = moveAnimation;
        Resources["DecimalConverter"] = new DecimalConverter();

        var frame = new Frame
        {
            WidthRequest = width,
            CornerRadius = 0,
            Padding = new Thickness(24, 20, 24, 20),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };

        var gridRowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection
        {
            new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto}, new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Star}
        };

        var grid = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions = gridRowDefinitions
        };

        var stackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };

        Grid.SetRow(stackLayout, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(contentView, 1);

        var label = new Label
        {
            FontFamily = "Roboto",
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            FontSize = 20,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            Margin = new Thickness(1),
            Text = MainResource.Filters
        };

        var imageButton = new ImageButton
        {
            Source = (FileImageSource)@"Assets/cross.png",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            Margin = new Thickness(1),
            Command = viewModel.CloseCommand
        };

        stackLayout.Children.Add(label);
        stackLayout.Children.Add(imageButton);

        grid.Children.Add(stackLayout);
        grid.Children.Add(contentView);
        frame.Content = grid;
            
        Content = frame;
    }
}
```

Xamarin.Forms version: 4.6.0.800 
Rg.Plugins.Popup version: 2.0.0.3

If you have any clue or idea where to even start fixing this problem, please, share it with me in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I use your code and test on the following simulators

- Android phone
- Android tablet
- iOS iPhone
- iOS iPad

It works fine , the appearing and disappearing animation works as expected .

I would suggest you update `Xamarin.Forms` and `Rg.Plugins.Popup version` package to the latest .

Comment: I guess migrating to xamarin.forms 5 or Rg.PLugins gonna fix that, thanks for your answer

Comment: Migrating will take really long, i ll mark you answer as accepted when it works

Comment: Hi , does it work or not ?

Comment: Project is really big, i tried updating rg, xamarin, but project stoped launching because of tons of errors. I am gonna perform migration, but its gonna take a while, maybe couple weeks or even months.

Comment: ok,no problem , good luck .